# jQuery .show & .hide not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am currently working on building a small menu that will change divs based upon which one it clicked. So if one is clicked it will show the div associated with it and hide the others, ect. But I cannot get it to work, nor can I figure out why. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Below is my code. I've clipped out the content as there was a lot of it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.mopHeader').click(function() {
    $('#raid-progress-mop').show();
    $('#raid-progress-cata').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-wotlk').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-tbc').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-vanilla').hide();
});

$('.cataHeader').click(function() {
    $('#raid-progress-mop').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-cata').show();
    $('#raid-progress-wotlk').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-tbc').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-vanilla').hide();
});

$('.wotlkHeader').click(function() {
    $('#raid-progress-mop').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-cata').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-wotlk').show();
    $('#raid-progress-tbc').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-vanilla').hide();
});

$('.tbcHeader').click(function() {
    $('#raid-progress-mop').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-cata').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-wotlk').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-tbc').show();
    $('#raid-progress-vanilla').hide();
});

$('.vanillaHeader').click(function() {
    $('#raid-progress-mop').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-cata').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-wotlk').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-tbc').hide();
    $('#raid-progress-vanilla').show();
});
</script>

<span class="h4">Raid Progress &nbsp; <span class="mopHeader">MoP</span> &nbsp; <span class="cataHeader">Cata</span> &nbsp; <span class="wotlkHeader">WotLK</span> &nbsp; <span class="tbcHeader">TBC</span> &nbsp; <span class="vanillaHeader">WoW</span></span> 


<div id="raid-progress-mop">
    <ul id="raid-mop">
        <li>Content A</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="raid-progress-cata">
    <ul id="raid-cata">
        <li>Content B</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="raid-progress-wotlk">
    <ul id="raid-wotlk">
        <li>Content C</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="raid-progress-tbc">
    <ul id="raid-tbc">
        <li>Content D</li>
    </ul>
</div>

<div id="raid-progress-vanilla">
    <ul id="raid-vanilla">
        <li>Content E</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps something like `$('#raid-progress-mop').show().siblings().hide()` would be preferable?

Comment: You need to wrap your jQuery into `$(document).ready(function(){ /*here!*/ });`

Comment: Glancing at a code block like that, you should immediately think "how can I avoid repeating myself"?

Comment: Aside from your original problem, [I've taken the liberty of modifying your HTML and condensing your code for you](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/2xdK6/). Any time you find yourself cutting and pasting the same code over and over, you should look for ways to simplify things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the script underneath your markup.  Either that, or put it inside *document.ready* callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // code here
});
```

The problem is that when the script appears above the markup, it will execute before the HTML is loaded, and so the browser won't yet know about *raid-progress-mop*, etc.

Comment: That fixed it, thanks. Can't believe I missed something like that O.o I'll accept as answer in 11 minutes when it allows me.

Answer (score 4):

Wrap your code in:

```
$(function(){ ... });
```

...which is the short form of:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ ... });
```

Cheers

Answer (score 2):

### *[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/afajax/2/edit)*

Wrap your code into a ready finction and this code I wrote is all you need:

```
$(function(){

  $('span[class$="Header"]').click(function(){
     var classNameSpecific = $(this).attr('class').split('Header')[0];
     $('div[id^="raid-progress-"]').hide();
     $('#raid-progress-'+classNameSpecific).show();     
  });

});
```

**Explanation:**

`$('span[class$="Header"]')` = target any `span` element which class **ends with** `Header`
Now just attach a click handler to all that spans.
Than, to hide all your `div` elements do:
`$('div[id^="raid-progress-"]').hide();` = will hide any `div` which `id` **starts with** `raid-progress-`
and than you just need to target the `div` that contains the magic word:
`$('#raid-progress-'+classNameSpecific).show();`

Comment: +1, was fiddling around and did'nt see your answer before I posted a few minutes too late, good one!

Comment: Thanks @adeneo! Wow, your rep is going sky-high! thumbs up for your effort on SO

Answer (score 2):

How about doing that a little more dynamically inside a `ready()` function :

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $('[class$="Header"]').on('click', function() {
            var myClass = $(this).attr('class').replace('Header', '');
            $('[id^="raid-progress"]').hide();
            $('#raid-progress-' + myClass).show();
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: +1 nice, but hard changes to classes. Hope just the OP does not style his elements by class-names

Answer (score 0):

$('.mopHeader') isn't defined yet. wrap your script with $(function(){...})